# osmdroid recenter after scrolling

Tags: android, osmdroid

I am looking for a way to get my app using osmdroid to recenter after I scroll to look around the map. I have enableFollowLocation() called but after scrolling, it no longer has my current position marker centered and does not recenter.
Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Go outside to get a good gps fix...  You may want to disable the follow while scrolling as it will keep jumping back if your getting good fixes.  You then need to re-enable it once the scrolling has finished.  If you want it to jump back when you have no gps fix then you will need to remember the centre point before scrolling and do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Declare a listener when you scrool or zoom like this "mapView.setMapListener(new MapListener()..."

```
            @Override
            public boolean onScroll(ScrollEvent event) {
                if(mMapView != null){
                    cameraChange(mMapView.getZoomLevel());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onZoom(ZoomEvent event) {
                if(mMapView != null){
                    cameraChange(mMapView.getZoomLevel());
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```